# How to safely delete folder contents before build

Tags: batch-file, ant, build, delete-file

Our nightly build loads the code in a folder (ex: `C:\build\nib_sw_12`)
I want to delete the before contents before the ANT loads the files from source control.

But there are some files which are not getting deleted

1. due to the fact that they have very long path (java doc files generated under nested folders)
2. Some 'exe' files are still running due to previous builds

I am wondering how I could delete files & folders with long path + killing the open (exe) files and deleting them?

I want to do this before the sw gets loaded from source control.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Environment: Win 2008 R2 x64, ANT

Comment: How do you want to delete directory? Using ant or in jenkins? You can kill process using taskkill app.

Comment: ANT would be better (command line perhaps?)

Comment: Did you try to delete files using `<delete>` task? It didn't delete files in long paths?

Comment: no..I haven't. Will that also take care of long paths? Anyway taskkill has to be used but point is to find the correct process as this server hosts many builds and I don't want to kill some other process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use taskkill to kill process, for example, to kill `app.exe` process just run `taskkill /im "app.exe" /f /t`. The problem may be when you will have few processes with the same name. To delete dir just use `<delete>` task, I think that it should delete long paths.

Comment: Try to find some program which can get process id using full path app.exe ant then use taskkill with that PID.

Answer (score 1):

you need the help of two *sysinternals* tools: **handle** and **pskill**. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533

you can then find the pid of the program that is locking the file

```
for /f "tokens=3 skip=4" %%a in ('handle my_file.dat') do echo %%a
```

and kill it

```
for /f "tokens=3 skip=4" %%a in ('handle my_file.dat') do pskill %%a
```

Comment: Sorry. Can't select 2 answers :-) but +1. Thanks a lot